# Display json feed data into html

Tags: javascript, html, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display data from below url to html page:

https://graph.facebook.com/1041049395967347/posts?access_token=616050815226195|bqcTMDgKwdzdDyOeD8uyIKEYZlo

(to display latest post from facebook).

Here it the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<h1>Customers</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/1041049395967347/posts?access_token=616050815226195|bqcTMDgKwdzdDyOeD8uyIKEYZlo";


xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr[i].story +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].story +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].created_time +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting any results.

Can anyone please help if I am missing anything?

Thank you

Comment: is `myFunction` getting called? Are you getting a 200 back from facebook?

Comment: yes,  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out; will get the output, if I change the link "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php" than I get output, but not with facebook graph url, check http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_server_sql

Comment: i followed this exaple http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_server_sql as i am not very familiar with json

Comment: I should also point out you have an XSS vulnerability in your code. Facebook does not guarantee that it escapes data it returns and you're sanitizing your output. For more info on how to mitigate this security problem I'd recommend diving into DOM building with this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion

Comment: Check to see if you're getting a 200 back from facebook. You could be getting a 401 or something and thus `myFunction` isn't being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/1041049395967347/posts?access_token=616050815226195|bqcTMDgKwdzdDyOeD8uyIKEYZlo",null,function(result){

    
  var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        result.data[i].story +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.data[i].story +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.data[i].created_time +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
  
  $("#divContent").html(out);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divContent"></div>
```

Comment: FOR ANYONE WHO WANT OS SEE FULL CODE, I have updated my question with final working code. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to update the **question** to make it work.  Future readers won't recognize the problem any more.

Comment: I have 1 more small question if you can help, I want to display facebook's created_time to a small date, for eg. 2016-04-06T02:01:21+0000 to "2016-04-06 02:01:21" or "2 hours ago". Is there any way?

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher Updated my question back to what is was before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is not an array but an object, containing the elements `data` and `paging`, so iterating over elements doesn't work. Instead, you should use arr.length:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/1041049395967347/postsaccess_token=616050815226195|bqcTMDgKwdzdDyOeD8uyIKEYZlo";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  var i;
  var out = "<table>";

  for (i = 0; i < arr.data.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" + 
        arr.data[i].story +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.data[i].story +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr.data[i].created_time +
        "</td></tr>";
  }
  out += "</table>";
  $("#divContent").html(out);
}
```

Comment: Got my vote for explaining the answer a bit instead of just fixing the code

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I wish I can mark multiple questions as answers.